# Vue @scroll not working.not triggering the function on @scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, vuejs3, vuetify.js, infinite-scroll

Vue @scroll not working. not triggering the function on @scroll. I am using vue3.here is my code

```
<div ref="scrollContainer" @scroll="handleScroll">
```

on scrolling the handle scroll is not triggering.in the handleScroll i trigger a function for load more data but it does'nt working.
anyone please help!!

Comment: It's not clear from your code if your div is actually scrollable.  Provide more information to show what you've done to set up a scrollable div.  Unless you put the scroll event on the entire window, you usually require at least 2 divs to create a scrollable area with 1 div constraining the visible height of the other and something like `overflow: scroll` on the container.  [See this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-babbage-rrlqf3?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: check the scrollTop of your div to see if it's the correct element, likely, it's another element that is scrolling, like the body or another div

Comment: thanks for this .its works from your sandbox code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.